# How much memory does MATLAB need to execute a function?

Tags: matlab, memory

I want to execute a function using a 48*48 image. However, it takes so much memory that I receive "out of memory" warning sometimes. I am trying to down-sample the image. Since low resolution may get worse result, I am wondering how to pick the best resolution image that uses smaller memory with better result.
Does anyone know any kinds of matlab build in functions which can display the memory it needs during the execution.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The memory required to store a 48x48 image is trivial and would not cause Matlab to run out of memory. You must be unintentionally keeping many images in memory. Are you using a for-loop or a similar looping construct in your code? Posting your code might get you a better answer.

Comment: whos command should display the memory taken by all the variables within a function